# Does "generic" tablet drivers exist?

Tags: drivers, graphics-tablet

I recently installed ubuntu 12.10 and it's awesome except that there does not seem to be any support for my drawing tablet.

This is what I got:
http://www.trust.com/products/product.aspx?ProductCategory=INPUT&ProductGroup=GRAPHIC-TABLETS&artnr=16937

I seem to be able to draw unless I lift the pen up for a second (like when normally moving around without holding it down to draw), after which the pointer becomes unresponsive for about 10 seconds, and then I can draw again.

So it's not the end of the world if I can't get it to work, but is there anything such as generic tablet drivers which would work in my case, or something specific for my tablet? I searched google but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a "generic" driver but the [DIGImend project](http://digimend.github.io/) is dedicated to making tablets work on Linux. If you look at [their compatibility list](http://digimend.github.io/tablets/) your tablet seems similar to the "Waltop Q Pad". You can also use `lsusb` to get the USB vendor and product IDs and look through that list to see if it's supported.